# .vbs (script) for copying a whole sheet from a file to another file

Tags: excel, vbscript

What .vbs code could I use to copy a whole sheet from an excel file to another?

I've tried using the following, but lines 2 and 3 pop an error ([Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQTO7.png)), and without them, the script runs but does nothing.

```
    Sub Copy_Sheet()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\File1.xls")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\File2.xlsx")

    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    y.Save
    y.close
    x.Close

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim xlapp ' as excel object 
Dim WSx, WSy ' as excel worksheet 
Dim x, y ' as workbook 
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set x = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\File1.xls")
Set y = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\File2.xlsx") 
Set WSx = x.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
Set WSy = y.Worksheets("Sheet1")
WSx.Copy WSy ' copy worksheet to other workbook
Set WSx = nothing 
Set WSy = nothing 
y.Save 
y.close 
x.Close
```

This should copy the worksheet from x to y without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
Dim xlapp ' as excel object
Dim WSx, WSy ' as excel worksheet
Dim x, y ' as workbook

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set x = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\File1.xls")
Set y = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\File2.xlsx")
Set WSx = x.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WSy = y.Worksheets("Sheet1")

WSy.Range("A1").value = WSx.Range("A1").value

Set WSx = nothing
Set WSy = nothing

y.Save
y.close
x.Close
```

Comment: Will this copy all the sheet or only the A1 value?

Comment: Hi Jose, only the "A1" value.  To copy all sheet, you can do a loop through all the sheet and copy to another workbook  using `For Each xlSheet in X.Sheets`  and use the function `xlSheet.copy` as in Dave's answer

Answer (score 0):

VBA typed Dims like

```
Dim x As Workbook
```

are illegal in VBScript (For diffs between VB and VBS start reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info)). This explains the error.